# weak_ptr vs unique_ptr reference - passing interface impl to other object

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is an example code:

```
class Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface(){}
    virtual void fun() = 0;
};

class InterfaceImpl: public Interface
{
public:
    void fun() override
    {}
};

class B
{
public:
    B(const std::shared_ptr<Interface>& impl /*std::unique_ptr<Interface>& impl* ?*/): impl_(impl){}
private:
    std::weak_ptr<Interface> impl_;
    //std::unique_ptr<Interface>& impl_; ?
};

class A
{
public:
    A(): impl_(std::make_shared<InterfaceImpl>()), b(impl_){}
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Interface> impl_;
    //std::unique_ptr<Interface> impl_ ?
    B b;
};
```

Class A contains an interface implementation and other object of type B. That object also need to use an interface implementation. I wonder which types of smart pointers should be used to create interface impl in class A and pass that impl to class B. Should I use shared_ptr in class A and weak_ptr in class B or unique_ptr in class A and a reference to unique ptr in class B ?

Comment: In 90%  of the situations you will be using a unique pointer. Chances are you don't need a weak pointer at all.

Comment: I wonder if using a reference to unique_ptr makes sense (conceptually) at all.

Comment: @Irbis I think normally it doesn't.

Comment: Is it valid to pass a null pointer to `B`'s constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the default choice should be that `A`, that *owns* the `Interface`, should hold it by `unique_ptr`. Then `B`, which does not own the `Interface`, should hold it by normal reference or raw pointer.

A reference to a `unique_ptr` rarely makes sense. It offers no additional safety guarantees over a raw pointer or a normal reference but adds confusion over ownership.

```
class Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface(){}
    virtual void fun() = 0;
};

class InterfaceImpl: public Interface 
{

public:
    void fun() override
    {}
};

class B
{
public:
    B(const Interface& impl): impl_(impl){}
private:
    const Interface& impl_;
};

class A
{
public:
    A(): impl_(std::make_unique<InterfaceImpl>()), b(*impl_){}
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Interface> impl_;
    B b;
};
```

This is assuming the lifetime of `B` is shorter than the lifetime of `A` so that `B` can guarantee that the `Interface` is alive. If you can't make that guarantee then you can start thinking about `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` pair but I don't think that should be your first choice. It looks like in your case you can make that guarantee.

As for whether `B` should hold a normal reference or a raw pointer that comes down to whether `impl_` can be null (which doesn't seem to be the case here). Also, holding a reference restricts what you can do with `B`. It makes it unassignable and you can't reseat the reference to point to a different impl.